# Adding a folder content in Git

Tags: git, github

So this is a bit weird. I'm working on a Git repository, and everything is fine. Until I added a folder named "tests" to the repository using `git add .`. I noticed that no files were added like Git used to do.

So I pushed to Github to check if files where actually added or not, because "test" is figuring out in my "git status" log (but none of "tests" files).

I got a weird green icon, and this is the first time that I stumble across it. You can see the icon  in the [github repository](https://github.com/omarabid/WordPress-Plugin-Boilerplate).

The commit log shows the following

`+Subproject commit 70b4cc379d0e1e749085ec1b3aaa0dd1cd0fc9b7`

So what does the icon mean and what did exactly happen?

**Edit**: I didn't add a submodule, and if there is one, there should have been a ".gitmodules" file created to track them. My guess is that Git got confused even though it shouldn't.

The cure was simple

```
git rm tests --cached
git add tests
git commit -m "fixed!"
```

Comment: The test folder was empty when you first added it in git?

Comment: No, it already had all the files. Actually, I didn't know Git add empty folders.

Comment: It don't, that's why i asked. You said that you added the folder, but no files were added, so i thought it could be empty. But that's not the case =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [radium](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1092630/radium) pointed out, you've added a new [`git submodule`](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules).

The last line in the output of `git show` confirms that you added a new subproject:

```
$ git show a068b76
commit a068b7629f29f8774db67a7384dbeee732a89adb
Author:
Date:   Wed May 8 17:18:47 2013 +0100

    Unit testing

diff --git a/.gitignore b/.gitignore
index d56bef9..30d9aa6 100644
--- a/.gitignore
+++ b/.gitignore
@@ -1,2 +1,3 @@
 .idea/
 .gitignore
+tests/wp-tests-config.php
diff --git a/tests b/tests
new file mode 160000
index 0000000..70b4cc3
--- /dev/null
+++ b/tests
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+Subproject commit 70b4cc379d0e1e749085ec1b3aaa0dd1cd0fc9b7
```

By any chance did you run `git submodule add <URL> tests` but forgot to add the file `.gitmodules` which was created, into git's version control ?

If you add a directory with a `.git` directory, `git` is merely going to ignore the `.git` and add all other files inside it. It will not create a new `Subproject commit` unless you explicitly ask it to create a new submodule.

Comment: No, I even checked the terminal history. I used the usual "git add ."

Answer (score 1):

That icon is Github's way of indicating that the folder is a [Git submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules).  Maybe have a look at your module configuration within Git to find out why it is setup that way.

Comment: Most likely, as the folder was another Git repository. I'll read that page and see what I can do about it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `git add -u` command to add newly created files / directories into git repo.

Comment: nope, the files weren't tracked to begin; look at radium answer, it's not about adding files.